# Azure AD Microsoft Account Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I am having the following problem:

Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status:
Body: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented}.

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Microsoft Account library

```html
Program file

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/page";
    options.LogoutPath = "/page";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/page?code={0}";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tiempoDeSesion);
    options.Cookie.Name = ".CookieName.Sec";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
    microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft-token");
    microsoftOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    microsoftOptions.TokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read");
    microsoftOptions.SaveTokens = true;
    microsoftOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    microsoftOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "displayName");
    microsoftOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "givenName");
    microsoftOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "surname");
    microsoftOptions.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson(ClaimTypes.Email,
                                   user => user.GetString("mail") ?? user.GetString("userPrincipalName"));
});
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/898979/aadsts700025-client-is-public-so-neither-39client.html

Comment: Public clients are applications such as mobile applications and single page JavaScript applications that can't keep secrets confidential. From [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/azure-api-for-fhir/register-public-azure-ad-client-app). Could you pls let us know the type of your application which is trying to integrate azure ad?

Answer (score 12):

The error ***"AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented"*** usually occurs if you are using Public Client Application and passing the **`client_secret`** to generate the access token.

You can verify whether your application is **Public client or not** like below:

[image]

Mobile and desktop applications are Public Client. If you want your Azure AD Application as public, then you can avoid giving **`client_secret`** parameter by excluding the below line in the code:

```java
microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
```

After excluding the **`client_secret`**, try generating the access token.

If you want your application as Confidential, then make sure to change your existing Azure AD Application/Create new Azure AD Application as **WEB** like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Authentication -> Save*

[image]

This configuration will make you Azure AD Application as confidential and you can pass **`client_secret`** to generate access token.

*I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via **Postman** and got the access token successfully for Web application like below:*

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

Please **note** that public applications are restricted, and they cannot pass any secrets.

**Reference:**

[Public and confidential client apps (MSAL) - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications)

Comment: @Paula-Code Just to add to that; sadly, the (Azure Portal) app-registration does not show/display a 'SPA' platform (/redirect URL) as being a 'Public client', so you also need to look at the 'spa' count too, and not just the "public client" count (in isolation).  But the backend (although happy with a 'Web' platform) will let you know that it doesn't like a configured 'SPA' platform (configured against the app-registration in this particular situation), with that same error message - "AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented."