# Issue with Microsoft Graph API and Azure AD SSO

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to configure the Microsoft Graph settings to read from User Profile but not having much success. I'm using a Blazor Server .NET 7 application.

I have an app registration up in Azure portal.

In my appSettings, I have:

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain",
    "TenantId": "mytenantId",
    "ClientId": "myClientId",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "mySecret"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

In Program.CS, I have the following:

```
string[] initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
              .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
              .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
              .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

//builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
//                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

When I run the app locally and try to login, I get an error:

```
MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details. Original exception: AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.
```

I'm a little confused because according to Microsoft's documentation, I need a client secret to use the GraphApi.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/how-to-build-a-blazor-web-app-with-azure-active-directory-authentication-and-microsoft-graph/

Also, if I remove:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
              .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
              .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
              .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

from Program.cs and just use:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Logging in/out works fine.

Any assistance on what I'm missing either in my code or maybe Azure portal?

Comment: A user Profile is a Windows Credential.  Most systems (including AZure and Microsoft Graph) are switching to OAUTH2 which is supported on Windows, Linux, and MAC.  Tokens are used with OAUTH2.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/troubleshoot-credssp

Answer (score 1):

The error "AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented" usually occurs if you are using Public Client Application and passing the client_secret to generate the access token.

InvalidClientPublicClientWithCredential - Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-error-codes)

It occurs the codes works fine when the TokenAcquisition code is removed

refer to a similar question below.

[Azure AD Microsoft Account Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766505/azure-ad-microsoft-account-client-is-public-so-neither-client-assertion-nor-c)